# Specifying date input format

Tags: asp.net, validation, date, formatting

I have a asp.net textbox for date input, I use regular expression to let the user input date in dd-mm-yyyy format but when i convert the input date in datetime object, the month and day values are interchanged.
How can a specify the right way for interpreting this input date?

Comment: How are you converting to DateTime?

Comment: I'm using 
DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(this.txtFromDate.Text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: I used DateTime.ParseExact(this.txtFromDate.Text,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.CultureInvariant) be careful with MM capital case letter, coz it's important :-) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by specifying a culture that uses the format dd-mm-yyyy like Germany:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("01-12-2009", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));
```

produces:

```
01 Dec 2009
```

Of course, you really want to do all of your culture specific processing in the culture of your user. So, `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")` should be `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

And if your user isn't used to seeing dates like dd-mm-yyyy, then don't use that format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting to use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) and specify your date format.

Answer (score 0):

I've used DateTime.Parse() in the past.

But it sounds like you are have culture issue, so this approach might be better:

```
  // Parse a date and time with no styles.
  dateString = "03/01/2009 10:00 AM";
  culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
  styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
  try
  {
     result = DateTime.Parse(dateString, culture, styles);
     outputBlock.Text += String.Format("{0} converted to {1} {2}.",
                       dateString, result, result.Kind.ToString()) + "\n";
  }
  catch (FormatException)
  {
     //Error
  }
```

More info on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8(VS.96).aspx

But you could also build the date time up if that works better:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(Y, M, D);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the app is running under a different culture to what you are expecting as user input. You might want to [change the culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) to the one you are expecting.